# Auto-answer questions for a GUI install program?

Tags: installation

During the install process, we are trying to install a third-party program along with our 'main' program that we install.  This third party application is very important (and can't be skipped).

The problem comes in here: the third-party program asks MANY questions when installing on Windows 7, and the user needs to know which are the 'correct' answers.  We've contacted the vendor and have never gotten a response (yes! We'll pay!).  We don't think a manual will help (who reads that?).  And, it's against our licensing to repackage their application into our Installer.

Theirs is a custom installer app, so nothing you've heard of - not INNO Setup or Installshield.

It's too late in the project to change vendors for this app, so what are my options?  Is there a program that we can run that will 'auto-answer' the questions this installer asks?

Comment: Some installers allow you to do a "silent install" where you can answer the "questions" by passing in command-line arguments.  Is this a possibility with this installer

Comment: This is truly a custom install app.  I'd bet everything they just wrote it from scratch in MFC.  Is there a way to mimic answering GUI questions from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something [sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) might be able to solve.  But regardless of your solution, you'll still have to distribute the program answering the installer along with the installer.  Or you can package them all up in another installer.

Comment: Although this wasn't ideal, it did seem to solve the problem.  The windows flash up and down pretty quickly, and most users won't think much about it.  (I personally think it looks 'hacky', but I think that at this point we were going to be hacky no matter what).  Anyway, QA/stakeholders liked it well enough.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI: we ended up using a program called macro-scheduler that has almost the exact same features.  After adjusting a few things I got this program to come up and go down within 3 seconds, installed and everything.  VERY happy with this solution (after a long while!)